# Assigning 15 Digits to Scala BigInt

Tags: scala, variable-assignment, bigint

I'm declaring a variable in Scala with type as BigInt and initialising a 10 digit number.

```
scala> var key: BigInt = 1234567890
key: BigInt = 1234567890
```

When I create another variable by doing a multiplication of the same `key` variable, the new variable gets the type as BigInt by default with more digits.

```
scala> var key_multp = key * key
key_multp: scala.math.BigInt = 1524157875019052100
```

When I try to assign a 15 digit value to a variable of type BigInt, it throws errors. How could I directly assign a variable of type BigInt with 15 digits value?

```
scala> var key:BigInt = 123456789012345
<console>:1: error: integer number too large
var key = 123456789012345
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: `var key = BigInt("123456789012345")`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It resolves. Didn't expect it to be this simpler :)

Comment: Since your number isn't that big you could also write it as long. e.g.: `val x: BigInt = 123456789012345L` or `val x = BigInt(123456789012345L)`

Answer (score 1):

Starting in `Scala 3`, and improvements brought to [numeric literals](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/numeric-literals.html), you can assign your `BigInt` as you intuitively tried to:

```
val big: BigInt = 1524157875019052100
// 1524157875019052100
```

or even with separators:

```
val big: BigInt = 1_524_157_875_019_052_100
// 1524157875019052100
```

And alternatively, as commented, and prior to Scala 3, using a `String` on `BigInt`'s constructor:

```
val big: BigInt = BigInt("1524157875019052100")
// 1524157875019052100
```